# Prove that $\tan{\beta}$ is rational

Tags: trigonometry, rationality-testing

> Suppose that $\tan{\alpha} = p/q$, where $p$ and $q$ are integers and $q \neq 0$. Prove that the number $\tan{\beta}$ for which $\tan{2\beta} = \tan{3\alpha}$ is rational only when $p^2+q^2$ is the square of an integer.

This is a pretty easy question to do if you are willing to do a lot of computations. With $\tan{\alpha} = p/q$, just simplify $\tan{2\beta} = \tan{3\alpha}$ using the sum of angles tangent formula. You will get a quadratic in $\tan{\beta}$ and you will have to show that $\sqrt{(p^2+q^2)^3}$ is rational iff $p^2+q^2$ is a perfect square.

There is an easier way to solve this question, though, and is given by the solution below. What I don't get is why $2\gamma = \alpha$. How did they arrive at that and did they use the fact that $\tan{2\beta} = \tan{3\alpha}$?

**Solution**

[image]

Comment: The solution has a gap, $\tan 2\beta =\tan 3\alpha$ should imply that $2\beta =n \pi +3\alpha$. Thus $2\beta -2\alpha=n \pi+ \alpha$.

Comment: We don't care about $\beta$ though.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by that comment because the very problem asks for $\tan \beta$.

Comment: Yes, we are curious about $\tan{\beta}$, but we don't need to find $\beta$ or talk about it.

Comment: I never indicated you have to compute $\beta$. The idea is that for any $\beta$ that satisfies the given equation the statement has to be proven. However the solution simply assumes that $2\beta = 3\alpha$, which is only one such $\beta$. Hence the gap. Not that the solution is incorrect, in fact it can still be fixed and made to work for any such $\beta$.

Comment: I don't see where the solution assumes that $2\beta = 3\alpha$. See the answer below for how they are getting $\gamma$.

Comment: Just read the first line of the solution below. After the word "easy". In fact even if you read the solution you have posted as part of the question, the very existence of $\gamma$ hinges on this equality.

Comment: I see what you are saying but we can take $2\beta = 3\alpha$ since the tangent is the same and we aren't really curious about angles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easy. $2\beta = 3\alpha \Rightarrow 2(\beta-\alpha) = \alpha$. So rename $\gamma = \beta - \alpha$.